# Why does it say expression must have pointer-to-object type? I don't want to use pointers. Only 2D array and everything less complex

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have no issues except in the upalph function at the end of the function.
The part where I'm assigning the array *siders*, and the next line where I'm printing out. The error appears under **col**. It says that the expression must have a pointer-to-object type.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int BL = 19;
int siders = 8;
void upalph();
//void sideNum(string boardBorder[BL][BL])
//{
//  for (int ROW = 0; ROW < BL; ROW++)
//  {
//      for (int COL = 0; COL < BL; COL++)
//      {
//          if (ROW >= 2 && ROW <= 16 && COL == 18 || ROW >= 2 && ROW <= 16 && COL == 0)
//          {
//              boardBorder[ROW][COL] = (int)siders; siders--;
//              cout << boardBorder[ROW][COL];
//          }
//      }
//  }
//}
void main()
{
    string boardBorder[BL][BL];

    for (int ROW = 0; ROW < BL; ROW++)
    {
        for (int COL = 0; COL < BL; COL++)
        {
            if (ROW >= 1 && ROW <= 17 && COL == 1 || ROW >= 1 && ROW <= 17 && COL == 17)
            {
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = "|";
            }
            else if (ROW >= 1 && ROW % 2 == 0 && COL >= 2 && COL % 2 != 0 && ROW <= 17 && COL <= 16)
            {
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = "|";
            }
            else if (ROW >= 1 && ROW % 2 != 0 && COL >= 2 && COL % 2 != 0 && ROW <= 17 && COL <= 16)
            {
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = "+";
            }
            else if (ROW >= 1 && ROW % 2 != 0 && COL >= 2 && COL % 2 == 0 && ROW <= 17 && COL <= 16)
            {
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = "-";
            }
            //else if (ROW >= 2 && ROW <= 16 && COL == 18 || ROW >= 2 && ROW <= 16 && COL == 0)
            //{
            //  boardBorder[ROW][COL] = sideNum; sideNum--;
            //}
            else
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = " ";
        }
    }
    upalph(boardBorder[BL][BL]);
    //sideNum(boardBorder);
    for (int ROW = 0; ROW < BL; ROW++)
    {
        for (int COL = 0; COL < BL; COL++)
        {
            if (COL == 0)
                cout << endl;
            cout << " " << boardBorder[ROW][COL];
        }
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}
void upalph(string boardBorder)
{
    for (int ROW = 0; ROW < BL; ROW++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < BL; col++)
        {
            if (ROW >= 2 && ROW <= 16 && col == 18 || ROW >= 2 && ROW <= 16 && col == 0)
            {
                boardBorder[ROW][col] = (int)siders; siders--;
                cout << boardBorder[ROW][col];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the upalph function ont the 9th and 10th line of upalph function, it's giving an error on **col**, saying that expression must have a pointer-to-object type.

Please help me out.
This is my first question here.

Comment: First of all you declare `upalph` as taking *no* arguments, then you call it to pass an argument. And the value you will pass is *out of bounds* of the array. Not to mention that inside the `upalph` function you use the `std::string` object as a matrix, which it isn't. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it seems you skipped some lessons of your class, or a couple of chapters in your books.

Comment: `upalph(boardBorder[BL][BL]);` - but, you previously declared that function as `void upalph();` which takes no arguments. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, remember that C-style arrays decay to pointers *really easily*. Maybe what you *really* want is a `std::array` or `std::vector` instead..